# 3 toggle sort of table column

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table of food and calories. I found snippets to allow me to sort the calorie column ASC and DESC. But what I would like to do is to have it also go back to the original display on the third click. So on page load, the table is in a certain order. On the first click, it sorts the table in ascending order by the values in the calorie column, on the second click it sorts in descending order. How would I go about, on the third click, to have it go back to the original order?
Here is the snippet I found, thanks to SO:

```
const sortTable = (f,n) => {
    var rows = $('.meal-foods-table tbody tr').get();
    rows.sort((a, b) => {

        var A = getVal(a);
        var B = getVal(b);
        if(A < B) {
            return -1*f;
        }
        if(A > B) {
            return 1*f;
        }
        return 0;
    });

    function getVal(elm) {
        var v = $(elm).children('td').eq(2).text().toUpperCase();
        if($.isNumeric(v)){
            v = parseInt(v,10);
        }
        return v;
    }

    $.each(rows, (index, row) => {
        $('.meal-foods-table').children('tbody').append(row);
    });
}

const sortHeaders = () => {
    var f_nm = 1;

    $("#cal").on('click', 'button.sort-cal', () => {
        f_nm *= -1;
        var n = $(this).prevAll().length;
        sortTable(f_nm,n);
    });
}
```

This is the HTML for the table:

```
<table class="meal-foods-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="hidden"></th>
        <th id='name'>Name</th>
        <th id='cal' class='cal-header'><button class='sort-cal'>Calories</button></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="meal-foods-body">
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

The table is populated dynamically, here is t he code for that part:

```
const prependMealFood = (food) => {
  $(`<tr id=${food.id}>
    <td><input id='food-${food.id}' type="checkbox"></td>
      <td class='food-name' contenteditable='true'>${food.name}</td>
      <td class='food-calories' contenteditable='true'>${food.calories}</td>
      </tr>`).prependTo('tbody.meal-foods-body')
}
```

Thanks for the help :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are destructively sorting. You are grabbing the list from the HTML, sorting it, and then pasting it back into the same place you grabbed it from. If you want to get back to the original sort order, you must keep a copy of the original list.

```
var originalRows = $('.meal-foods-table tbody tr').get();
const sortTable = (f,n) => {
    var rows;
    if(f == 0) {
        $.each(originalRows, (index, row) => {
            $('.meal-foods-table').children('tbody').append(row);
        });
        return;
    }
    rows = [].concat(originalRows);
    rows.sort((a, b) => {

        var A = getVal(a);
        var B = getVal(b);
        if(A < B) {
            return -1*f;
        }
        if(A > B) {
            return 1*f;
        }
        return 0;
    });

    function getVal(elm) {
        var v = $(elm).children('td').eq(2).text().toUpperCase();
        if($.isNumeric(v)){
            v = parseInt(v,10);
        }
        return v;
    }

    $.each(rows, (index, row) => {
        $('.meal-foods-table').children('tbody').append(row);
    });
}
const sortHeaders = () => {
    var f_nm = -1;

    $("#cal").on('click', 'button.sort-cal', () => {
        var n = $(this).prevAll().length;
        switch(f_nm) {
          case 0:
            f_nm = -1;
            break;
          case -1:
            f_nm = 1;
          default:
            f_nm = 0;
        }
        sortTable(f_nm,n);
    });
}
```

Comment: Omg Thank you! That makes so much sense that I feel embarrassed, lol.